# Why does reading input sometimes skips newline character when trying to clear input buffer?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, nasm, input-buffer

When I input an odd number of characters it works as expected, but when an even number of characters is entered it waits for user input inside of the `.clearBuffer` procedure. I am using NASM on Windows.

```
global _start

extern _GetStdHandle@4
extern _WriteConsoleA@20
extern _ExitProcess@4
extern _ReadConsoleA@20

%define STDIN dword -10
%define STDOUT dword -11

section .data
    menuText: db '---menu---', 0Dh, 0Ah, 0,\
    '1. Start', 0Dh, 0Ah, 0,\
    '2. Generate field', 0Dh, 0Ah, 0,\
    '3. Settings', 0Dh, 0Ah, 0,\
    '4. Quit', 0Dh, 0Ah, 0
    inputText: db 'Enter: '
    inputTextL: equ $ - inputText
    invalid: db 'Invalid input', 0Dh, 0Ah
    invalidL: equ $ - invalid

section .bss
    stdin: resd 1
    stdout: resd 1
    
    numCharsWritten: resd 1
    numCharsRead: resd 1
    input: rest 1

section .text
_start:
    push STDOUT
    call _GetStdHandle@4
    mov [stdout], eax
    
    push STDIN
    call _GetStdHandle@4
    mov [stdin], eax
    
    call printMenu
    
    ;print "Enter: "
    mov ebx, inputTextL
    mov ecx, inputText
    call write
    
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, input
    call read
    
    ;mov ebx, 1
    ;mov ecx, input
    ;call .write
    
    call clearBuffer
    
    jmp _start
    
    
printMenu:
    mov ecx, 0
    
.printMenuLoop:
    cmp ecx, 5
    jnz .printMenuText
    ret
    
.printMenuText:
    push ecx
    call .getMenuText
    
    push ecx
    mov ecx, ebx
    mov ebx, eax
    call write
    pop ecx
    add ecx, 1
    jmp near .printMenuLoop
    
;input
;index
;output
;eax - length
;ebx - str
;ecx - index
.getMenuText:
    mov eax, 0;eax - current index/length
    mov ebx, 0;ebx - offset/string
    
    cmp eax, [esp + 4]
    je .getMenuTextL2
    
.getMenuTextL1:;find string
    add ebx, 1
    cmp byte [menuText + ebx], 0
    jne .getMenuTextL1
    
    add eax, 1
    cmp eax, [esp + 4]
    jl .getMenuTextL1
    
.getMenuTextL2:
    add ebx, menuText
    pop eax
    pop ecx
    push eax
    mov eax, 0
    
.getMenuTextL3:;find length
    add eax, 1
    cmp byte [ebx + eax], 0
    jne .getMenuTextL3
    
    ret

;input
;ebx - length, ecx - string
write:
    push dword 0
    push numCharsWritten
    push ebx
    push ecx
    push dword [stdout]
    call _WriteConsoleA@20
    ret

;input
;ebx - amount, ecx - location
read:
    push dword 0
    push numCharsRead
    push ebx
    push ecx
    push dword [stdin]
    call _ReadConsoleA@20
    ret

clearBuffer:
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, input
    call read
    
    ;mov ebx, 1
    ;mov ecx, input
    ;call .write
    
    cmp byte [input], 0Ah
    jne clearBuffer
    ret

;input
;eax - exit value
exit:
    push dword eax
    call _ExitProcess@4
```

I've tried using the `_FlushConsoleInputBuffer@4` at the end of `.read` before the return, but that didn't do anything.
I based my clear buffer code on: [Clear input buffer Assembly x86 (NASM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63840074/clear-input-buffer-assembly-x86-nasm)

But as stated, it's not fully working for me.

Any help on why this is happening and how to go about fixing it would be appreciated.

Comment: IDK about correctness, sorry.  Maybe Windows is different from Linux / Unix in some way.  For efficiency, you'd normally want to save the `GetStdHandle` result somewhere, perhaps a global variable.  Especially if you're already doing something as inefficient as multiple 1-byte `read` calls, calling GetStdHandle for every byte is even worse.

Comment: Style note: your functions like `.clearBuffer` are basically stand-alone functions, not really part of `_start`, so normally you'd give them non-local names (which don't start with a dot).  Like `clearBuffer`, so the full name is just `clearBuffer`, not `_start.clearBuffer`.  Use dot local labels for stuff like tops of loops within one function.

Comment: In Windows, does a newline read as CR/LF, or just the `0Ah` line feed you're checking for?  I don't think that would explain anything either way, though.

Comment: Windows does puts CR/LF(`0D0Ah`), but `0Ah` is the character at the end of that sequence, so I only need to check for that I believe. And it also registers a newline as `0Ah` I believe also for compatibility(I could be wrong)

Comment: Yeah, looking for the `0Ah` at the end should be fine.  Being 2 bytes vs. 1 from the final keypress does change what odd vs. even means for how many bytes are left to read after your `_start` reads the first one, but IDK why reading one at a time wouldn't work.  You are using `_ReadConsoleA` not `_ReadConsoleW` (UTF-16 wide characters).  Hmm, but I wonder if perhaps your console is giving you UTF-16 text anyway?  Again, I don't see why that would explain the problem, but odd vs. even makes me suspicious of 2-byte character encodings.

Comment: You were right! I changed it to `_ReadConsoleW` and it is working! I can't thank you enough. I was so confused why it wasn't working